# How do I add dynamic javascript to the head tag from a string, not a file?

Tags: javascript

I am using Javascript to generate additional custom javascript and then adding it to the HEAD tag.  The code below works great adding a javascript file, but what if the script is in a variable just generated?

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
scriptTag.setAttribute("src", "myfile.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: In a variable how? Source code as a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   // script text
var txt = "alert('foo');";

var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

   // append it in a text node
scriptTag.appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

---

FWIW, you don't need a script tag for this. You can use the `Function` constructor instead.

```
var txt = "alert('foo');";

Function(txt)();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");

scriptTag.innerHTML = "What you want here";///....

document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fPM74/)

Comment: Thanks Gordon, when I do that I get a function not found.  When I  inspect the element with Chrome it shows the new SCRIPT tag in the HEAD, but it is always empty and the string being assigned to .innerHTML does have a value.

Comment: @VincentJames: You'll want to get rid of the `"src"` attribute that is being added.

Comment: @VincentJames. Check out the demo.

Answer (score 1):

Both answers seem ok specially the one from @gdoron.

I've written a simple example in case you want to do the same thing in jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/bitoiu/EKpGg/

Snippet:

```
$(function(){

    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    // script.url = 'some valid url';
    $('head').append( script );
});​
```