# Dynamically add JS code to head tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, head

I am trying to add a script to the head tag of my page. I am seeing the code that I am trying to add in the body tag but it doesn't show up in head tag.

```
$(document).load(function() {
   $('<script>console.log("hi");</' + 'script>').appendTo("head")
});
```

I see this being added in `<body>` but I dont see it in `<head>`.

I tried variations of append, appendTo and document.ready and document.load functions. None of those worked so far.

I went through cpuple of similar threads before I posted. I didn't seem to fix my issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13388018/894111

Comment: if script is working what difference does it make where it ends up anyway? WHat is the higher level problem?

Comment: For some google analytics reason, i want this script to be added into head tag

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might need to do is escape the `</` as `<\/`

If its an inline script though maybe you can try just adding a setTimeout to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following function:

```
(function (src) {
    var tagName = 'script', script = document.createElement(tagName);
    script.src = src;
    var elm = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[0];
    elm.parentNode.insertBefore(script, elm);
})('SCRIPT.SRC.HERE.js');
```

This will create a dynamic `script` tag and add it before the first `script` tag. Although it won't work in the way you want if you don't have any `script` tags inside your `head`. In this case, you could use the following function:

```
(function (src) {
    var tagName = 'script', script = document.createElement(tagName);
    script.src = src;
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.insertBefore(script, head.childNodes[0]);
})('SCRIPT.SRC.HERE.js');
```

This will directly get the first element inside your `head` tag and append the new script before it.

Comment: Your code works. You can also use `document.head.appendChild(script);`

Answer (score 0):

The `document` doesn't fire a "load" event - or if it does, it's a bubbled event from something else loading (like another script or image file). Try changing `document` to `window`:

http://jsfiddle.net/5bhmwyrx/3/

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var script = $('<script>console.log("hi");</' + 'script>').appendTo(document.head);
   console.log("Script was appended to", script[0].parentNode.nodeName);
   //-> Script was appended to HEAD
});

$(document).load(function() {
   console.log("You should never see this");
});

document.onload = function () {
    console.log("You should not see this in modern browsers");
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but still I dont see it in head tag

Comment: if you look at this, it does fire an onload event like window does (see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/588048/3769412) but it helps that the OP is using jQuery to deal with this, anyway which would smooth out anything and isn't answering the question OP asked anyway

Comment: @Daemedeor - `document.onload = function () { console.log("document onload event"); };` doesn't log anything (in current browsers). That's so old it's not even implemented in browsers any more and was the JS api to `<body onload="">` - super super old school.

Comment: @user3861559 - Did you try my fiddle?? Here is proof that it's being appended to the HEAD (look at the console): http://jsfiddle.net/5bhmwyrx/2/